# How can I open a port in OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, firewall, port

My system is a MacBook Air, so I cannot plug into the modem directly. And I do not want to turn my firewall off.

**How can I specify to open a port, like port 56789 in Mac OS 10.6.8?**

I know in the old Mac OS, there is an option for me to specify a custom port. But I cannot find it in OS X 10.6.8. In `System Preferences` / `Security` / `Firewall`, I only can allow an *applicaiton* to access a new port.

However, now I'm programming, using a new port. So, it does not seem suitable for me. Can I simply open a port instead of using an Application to open a port?

Comment: What are you programming in? How would you open the port from there?

Comment: perl? Can I? I dont' know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

When your application opens a socket to listen on a port, the OS will automatically ask whether you will allow this or not.

If you want more control, you can use tools like [Waterroof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/), but this can be much more difficult to configure.

Comment: I know it will allow me to application. As you can see, I wanna manually handle the ports. Does Mac have any default system setting configure it? instead of using other tools?

Comment: I suppose there may be some command line tools, but the point of the firewall is simple security. It would be quite strange for OS X to have something like Windows Advanced Firewall.

Comment: Yes, I saw it in windows before. So, I am finding sth like that. And even command line is fine. If there is no, I think I need sth third party.